# R Take Non-sampled Rows from a Data Frame

Tags: r, random

In R I can take a random sample of half the rows of a dataframe like this:

```
data(iris);  model_data <- iris
data  <- model_data
half  <- (nrow(model_data))%/%2
train <- model_data[sample(nrow(model_data), half), ]
```

However, I also need a simple way to take the rows that were not sampled and put them in another object called `val` for validation.

Comment: `s <- sample(nrow(model_data), half); val <- model_data[-s,]` Without a reproducible example, that's about all I can suggest

Comment: @RichardScriven I didn't think the specific data mattered, but to make it reproducible you could just add `data(iris);  model_data <- iris`. I will test your solution now. Thanks!

Comment: Every time I do that I spend 4 hours in the comments of my answers trying to figure out what OP actually wants and quite frankly I'm tired of doing that :)

Comment: @RichardScriven Fair enough. Would you like to add your answer as a solution? I tried it on the iris data and my real data. It definitely selects the right number of rows to put into the new object. I can't be 100% sure that it's actually selecting the non-sampled rows, but that's what it seems like and your solution looks good to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function to keep `train` and `val` together, maybe something like

```
foo <- function(data) {
    samp <- sample(nrow(data), nrow(data)/2)
    list(train = data[samp,], val = data[-samp,])
}
foo(mtcars)
foo(iris)
```